# Note Taking App for Android with Hierarchies

Tags: android, note-taking

I need recommendations for an Android smartphone note taking/note organizing app.

Requirements:

1) be able to organize notes in a hierarchy maybe four or five levels deep

2) be able to have links to web pages within the notes

This is for a large collection of quotes and book/article excerpts that I have from numerous writers on various topics, which I want to have organized and at my fingertips for easy access.

Comment: Some of the Wiki or Markdown editors could come in handy for that (see [my lists here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_106)). Both allow you to link to web pages, and you could have a hierarchy inside a single document (using multiple heading levels). I'm not sure which app offers hierarchical note structures and links in a different way.

Comment: Do you want data stored locally on your device or stored in the cloud as a service?

Comment: Just locally, Basil.

Comment: I was thinking that it would also be helpful to be able to apply tags to the notes so that I could quickly see all the ones that are tagged by a certain topic, while also having them organized in a hierarchy. Please recommend any apps that allow for that sort of tagging, in addition to the other two things I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft [OneNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.onenote)

- Since the basic form of OneNote is free across all platforms (Android, PC, [Web](https://www.onenote.com/?public=1&wdorigin=ondcauth2&wdorigin=ondc)), the same notebook(s) can be accessed from any device, with all changes synced in real time.

  - The full version contained within Microsoft Office/Office365 significantly expands what one is able to do with OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

[Orgzly](http://www.orgzly.com/) is an Android app for reading and editing Emacs [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/) files. Tree-like hierarchical structure with unlimited depth is a core pillar of org-mode. The org-mode files are stored in plain text and you can edit them in any other platform you want. It also supports various advanced customizable features, making it especially liked by programmers and people from the scientific communities in general.

Answer (score 0):

"Vault 3 outliner" is my best choice. I started use Vault from 1995, and now the version can use in Window and Android. It helped me a lot in last 20 years as a handy note for different projects management. I also use it to keep as a home database.
Please visit : https://ericbt.com/.  or search from Google Play. I highly recommend it. 
I use only this Apps to keep all my data in last 20 years. Sometimes I use Listpro. But later find Listpro only work in iphone, then I just use Vault 3 outliner.When I need to keep photo , I use MyNotekeeper : http://www.mynoteskeeper.com/. (But it only work in Window). 
By using these 2 applications, that already enough to keep most of your idea.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you please specify how your recommendation satisfies the OP's requirements?